# VectorPlot: How can I evaluate the vector field by clicking on the plot?

Tags: plotting

This seems like a basic feature that is somehow missing. Ideally we'd get something like a tooltip which shows the x,y position where I click (or of where the mouse is currently hovering) and the evaluated vector (or scalar in the case of a scalar field) at that position. I think this would be a great way to "get a feel for" the values because by default the arrows are scaled automatically so they fit so I don't know anything about the relative magnitude of a particular arrow.

I have found that [this is a good way](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/howto/GetCoordinatesForPointsInAPlot.html) to get a tooltip which displays the current mouse coordinates really well, but it obviously won't evaluate my vector field for me.

Comment: For the case of scalar field plot it's quite easy to see what's going on by just doing a 3D plot with it.

Comment: Something like `VectorPlot[{y, -x}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}] /. ar : Arrow[{p1_, p2_}] :> Tooltip[Arrow[{p1, p2}], p1]`?

Comment: @J.M. That's pretty good

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. For example, using **[LocatorPane](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LocatorPane.html)**. Imagine this is your vector function:

```
f[x_, y_] := {-1 - x^2 + y, 1 + x - y^2}
```

Now this will do the trick, where first line is the coordinate, and second is the function **f** evaluated at the coordinate. Red dot will follow the mouse. You can also bring the numbers with `PlotLabel` outside the graphics not to block the view.

```
DynamicModule[{pt = {1, 0}},LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt], 
  VectorPlot[f[x, y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, StreamPoints -> Coarse, 
   StreamColorFunction -> Hue, Epilog -> Dynamic@Inset[{pt, f @@ pt}, pt], 
   PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], AutoAction -> True, 
   Appearance -> Style["\[FilledCircle]", Red]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Since the plot itself is static you can also do `VectorPlot[..., Epilog -> Dynamic[...]]` instead of `Dynamic[VectorPlot[....]]`. On my system this makes the plot a lot more responsive.

Comment: @Heike Excellent point. The rule of thumb with `Dynamic` is to try bring it to the lowest level to avoid recomputing redundant things. I made the changes.

Comment: This is beautiful.